# bash (grep|awk|sed) - Extract domains from a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I need to extract domains from a file.

domains.txt:

```
eofjoejfej fjpejfe http://ejej.dm1.com dêkkde
ojdoed www.dm2.fr doejd eojd oedj eojdeo
http://dm3.org ieodhjied oejd oejdeo jd
ozjpdj eojdoê jdeojde jdejkd http://dm4.nu/
io d oed 234585 http://jehrhr.dm5.net/hjrehr
[2014-05-31 04:05] eohjpeo jdpiehd pe dpeoe www.dm6.uk/jehr
```

I need to get:

dm1.com
dm2.fr
dm3.org
dm4.nu
dm5.net
dm6.co.uk

Comment: `I need to get ....`! where is your question? 2) how come you want to have `dm6.co.uk`? does it exist in input file?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? for what I can tell, the problem lies on how to determine the regex for the domain. Do your url follow a specific pattern or are they completly random ? Otherwise names like `http://my.cool.custom.name.dm1.co.uk` will be a pain to match

Answer (score 3):

Try this sed command,

```
$ sed -r 's/.*(dm[^\.]*\.[^/ ]*).*/\1/g' file
dm1.com
dm2.fr
dm3.org
dm4.nu
dm5.net
dm6.uk
```

Comment: Are we sure they are at the most once per line?

Comment: posted according to the op's input.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit long, but should work:

```
grep -oE "http[^ ]*|www[^ ]*" file | sed -e 's|http://||g' -e 's/^www\.//g' -e 's|/.*$||g' -re 's/^.*\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+$)/\1/g'
```

Output:

```
dm1.com
dm2.fr
dm3.org
dm4.nu
dm5.net
dm6.uk
```

Answer (score 2):

Unrefined method using grep and sed:

```
grep -oE '[[:alnum:]]+[.][[:alnum:]_.-]+' file | sed 's/www.//'
```

Outputs:

```
ejej.dm1.com
dm2.fr
dm3.org
dm4.nu
jehrhr.dm5.net
dm6.uk
```

Comment: `ejej.dm1.com` is not a domain name. OP would like to extract `dm1.com`

Comment: @Ploutox Yeah it's obvious. He didn't say it explicitly though, so giving a quick answer open for changes isn't bad. I hope you noticed the word 'Unrefined'.

Answer (score 1):

An answer with gawk:

```
LC_ALL=C gawk -d -v RS="[[:space:]]+" -v FS="." '
  {
    # Remove the http prefix if it exists
    sub( /http:[/][/]/, "" )

    # Remove the path
    sub( /[/].*$/, "" )

    # Does it look like a domain?
    if ( /^([[:alnum:]]+[.])+[[:alnum:]]+$/ ) {

      # Print the last 2 components of the domain name
      print $(NF-1) "." $NF

    }

  }' file
```

Some notes:

- Using `RS="[[:space:]]"` allow us to process each group of letter independently.
- `LC_ALL=C` forces `[[:alnum:]]` to be ASCII-only (this is not necessary any more with gawk 4+).

Answer (score 1):

To be able to remove subdomains you have to validate them first, because if you cut the columns it would affect the TLDs. Then you have to do 3 steps.

**Step 1**: clean `domains.txt`

```
grep -oiE '([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}\.){1,}(\.?[a-zA-Z]{2,}){1,}' domains.txt | sed -r 's:(^\.*?(www|ftp|ftps|ftpes|sftp|pop|pop3|smtp|imap|http|https)[^.]*?\.|^\.\.?)::gi' | sort -u > capture
```

Content `capture`

```
ejej.dm1.com
dm2.fr
dm3.org
dm4.nu
jehrhr.dm5.net
dm6.uk
```

**Step 2**: download and filter TLD list:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/publicsuffix/list/master/public_suffix_list.dat
grep -v "//" public_suffix_list.dat | sed '/^$/d; /#/d' | grep -v -P "[^a-z0-9_.-]" |  sed 's/^\.//' |  awk '{print "." $1}' |  sort -u > tlds.txt
```

So far you have two lists (`capture` and `tlds.txt`)

**Step 3**: Download and run this python script:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maravento/blackweb/master/bwupdate/tools/parse_domain_tld.py && chmod +x parse_domain_tld.py && python parse_domain_tld.py | sort -u
```

out:

```
dm1.com
dm2.fr
dm3.org
dm4.nu
dm5.net
dm6.uk
```

Source: [blackweb](https://github.com/maravento/blackweb)

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful:

```
grep -Pho "(?<=http://)[^(\"|'|[:space:])]*" file.txt | sed 's/www.//g' | grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]]{1,}\.[[:alnum:]]{1,}[.]{0,1}[[:alnum:]]{0,}' | sort | uniq
```

First grep get 'http://www.example.com' enclosed in single or double quotes, but extract only domain. Second, using 'sed' I remove 'www.', third one extract domain names separated by '.' and in block of two or three alfnumeric characters. At the end, output is ordered to display only single instances of each domain